# How to format multiple columns of text, each column being left aligned?

Tags: python

I am currently trying to get this output with my python code:

```
Three of Spades    Four of Spades     Seven of Spades    Ten of Spades 
Queen of Clubs     Three of Clubs     King of Diamonds   Nine of Spades 
Seven of Clubs     Jack of Hearts     Six of Hearts      King of Hearts 
Ten of Diamonds    Eight of Clubs     Three of Hearts    Ace of Hearts 
Nine of Clubs      Eight of Spades    Ten of Hearts      Nine of Hearts 
Jack of Diamonds   Five of Clubs      King of Spades     Ace of Clubs 
Deuce of Spades    Deuce of Diamonds  Queen of Diamonds  Six of Spades 
Four of Hearts     Ace of Diamonds    Five of Diamonds   Six of Clubs 
Jack of Spades     Eight of Hearts    Ace of Spades      Six of Diamonds 
Ten of Clubs       Deuce of Clubs     Deuce of Hearts    Five of Spades 
Seven of Diamonds  King of Clubs      Nine of Diamonds   Queen of Spades 
Four of Clubs      Five of Hearts     Four of Diamonds   Seven of Hearts 
Eight of Diamonds  Queen of Hearts    Three of Diamonds  Jack of Clubs
```

Here is my code printing the output:

```
counter = 0
for value, suit in initialize_deck():
    if counter % 4 == 0:
        print()
    counter += 1
    print(f'{value:5} of {suit:9}', end=' ')
```

(initialize_deck()) is a function previously defined earlier in my code, which returns a shuffled list of tuples containing each card and suit combination.

This is the best output I have managed to get:

```
Four  of Spades    Five  of Hearts    Queen of Diamonds  Six   of Clubs     
Ace   of Hearts    Ace   of Spades    Eight of Diamonds  Nine  of Diamonds  
King  of Diamonds  King  of Clubs     Jack  of Spades    Deuce of Hearts    
King  of Hearts    Eight of Spades    Five  of Diamonds  Seven of Diamonds  
Ten   of Clubs     King  of Spades    Three of Hearts    Seven of Clubs     
Deuce of Clubs     Jack  of Diamonds  Eight of Clubs     Seven of Spades    
Eight of Hearts    Queen of Clubs     Six   of Spades    Ten   of Diamonds  
Ace   of Diamonds  Four  of Diamonds  Five  of Clubs     Jack  of Clubs     
Nine  of Spades    Jack  of Hearts    Ten   of Spades    Queen of Spades    
Nine  of Clubs     Deuce of Diamonds  Six   of Diamonds  Queen of Hearts    
Nine  of Hearts    Three of Clubs     Seven of Hearts    Ten   of Hearts    
Five  of Spades    Four  of Hearts    Six   of Hearts    Deuce of Spades    
Ace   of Clubs     Four  of Clubs     Three of Diamonds  Three of Spades
```

I don't want any gaps between the segments of text, but I want each colum to be in a nice line.

Comment: You should format the combination string rather than formatting the card and suit separately

Comment: Have you tried using "\t" to seperate the spaces?

Comment: Maybe try the .strip() method.

Answer (score 2):

You need to first create a string containing `{value} of {suit}`, and then format *this string* to the required width.

```
for counter, (value, suit) in enumerate(initialize_deck()):
    if counter % 4 == 0:
        print()
    card = f'{value} of {suit}'
    print(f'{card:18}', end=' ')
```

This gives your desired output:

```
Three of Spades    Four of Spades     Seven of Spades    Ten of Spades      
Queen of Clubs     Three of Clubs     King of Diamonds   Nine of Spades     
Seven of Clubs     Jack of Hearts     Six of Hearts      King of Hearts     
Ten of Diamonds    Eight of Clubs     Three of Hearts    Ace of Hearts      
Nine of Clubs      Eight of Spades    Ten of Hearts      Nine of Hearts     
Jack of Diamonds   Five of Clubs      King of Spades     Ace of Clubs       
Deuce of Spades    Deuce of Diamonds  Queen of Diamonds  Six of Spades      
Four of Hearts     Ace of Diamonds    Five of Diamonds   Six of Clubs       
Jack of Spades     Eight of Hearts    Ace of Spades      Six of Diamonds    
Ten of Clubs       Deuce of Clubs     Deuce of Hearts    Five of Spades     
Seven of Diamonds  King of Clubs      Nine of Diamonds   Queen of Spades    
Four of Clubs      Five of Hearts     Four of Diamonds   Seven of Hearts    
Eight of Diamonds  Queen of Hearts    Three of Diamonds  Jack of Clubs
```

Note that I used `enumerate` to count the iterations instead of maintaining a counter manually, but that is irrelevant to formatting the text.